# Trouble downloading a file due to lack of permission

Tags: windows-7, permissions, download

After downloading this file:  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/315/hon/hon_update.exe before it actually copies to my computer I get this error:

```
File Access Denied <title of box> 

You need permission to perform this action.

You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this file.
```

Within this box are to buttons: Try Again or Cancel

I have searched other similar "permission" type questions, but they seem to all refer to existing files or folders. How do I give permission to a file which doesn't exist yet? (since it is in the process of downloading and hasn't finally copied over yet)

I am running Windows 7 64 bit. I would be happy to supply any other information to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this error message refers to the location you are copying the file to, as opposed to the file being copied. It may be worth changing the folder that you use for downloads, perhaps use a different method to download, also.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have just tried to redownload and save to desktop, download folder, root C: drive and a public folder. Each time with the same permission error. No luck yet, but still optimistic for the answer

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. It just though it was worth a try, as I was able to download the file easily enough. Just out of interest, what are you using to do the download?

Comment: Hmmm. That's an interesting question. I just click the link and a download box opens. So I am using Windows 7? How else could someone download (like what else would you use to download?)

Comment: I was wondering if it was a browser issue. I initially used firefox but I can also download the file in IE. It also doesn't matter if I'm using an administrative account or a standard user account. Do you have an alternative account on that PC you could use?